# Hibernate Named Query and Spring Data SQL injection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, named-query

I want to add auto complete to search in my app. For this feature i used NamedQuery("userSuggest"). In JpaRepository I define a method("userSuggest") with one parameter.
Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "User.userSuggest", query = "select u from User u where u.userName like :userName") })
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;

    setter and getter ...
}
```

and

```
 @Repository("userRepository")
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
        List<Gene> userSuggest(@Param("userName") String userName);
    }
```

I call this method by pass user input data + percent sign as parameter:

```
userRepository.userSuggest(userInpoutData + "%");
```

Now Problem:
when user pass "%" (userInpoutData="%") the method return all existing user in database. How can I prevent this SQL injection?
I know that using entityManager.createNamedQuery(like [How To Fix SQL Injection: JPA](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-persistence-api-jpa)) solve this problem but i don't know how to use it with Spring JpaRepository.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not SQL injection. It is because of this:

```
userRepository.userSuggest(userInpoutData + "%");
```

So you get:

```
%%
```

Try this:

```
if (!userInpoutData.isEmpty() && !userInpoutData.equals("%") {
    userRepository.userSuggest(userInpoutData + "%");
}
```

Comment: I assume this is a sql injection so to solve this problem, I must be scape wildcard. Thanks